# No longer able to use WiFi, adapter Intel WiFi Link 5100, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

Computer: Acer Aspire 7730. Only Ubuntu installed.

Hi, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday and WiFi worked out of the box. But now the WiFi does not work anymore. It was after I did a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in order to try to fix Spotify (native) (couldn't start it), but I've since learned that update does not actually update any packages (correct me if I'm wrong). But if was after the reboot (Ubuntu wanted me to reboot) that my WiFi no longer works.

If I type

```
sudo lshw -c network
```

This is the output:

```
   *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0a00000-c0a01fff
```

So my WiFi adapter is unclaimed, which I've read means that no driver is associated with it.

Also:

```
iwconfig
```

gives

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

[This](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) is the link that I wanted to use to try to install `iwlwifi` (I first wanted to try a Linux driver instead of the whole Windows wireless Driver thing. Plus when I tried to find the driver for this adapter, I could only find `.exe` files, while it said that I should find `.inf` files).

Running this

```
cd /lib/firmware
ls *.ucode
```

gives

```
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode  iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode  iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode   iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode  iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode   iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode  iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode   iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode  iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode  iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode  iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
```

Notice the `iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode`. This looks very similar to the file(s) that I downloaded from the previous website that I showed. So since it is already there, I haven't tried to install it to that directory yet (and I'm not quite certain how to do it). Maybe the kernel/system/whatever simply doesn't load the driver on boot-up?

Most of the problems I've had with Ubuntu so far have been solved with copy pasting terminal commands without knowing what they do, but it feels like the more I do this the more brittle the whole system becomes (because I don't know what I'm doing). It seems that installing and updating software can lead to unforeseen, bad side-effects that I don't have the skill to foresee. So for this problem I want to ask someone directly before I proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver for your card, iwlwifi, is already present in the 12.04 kernel, as is the required firmware. Let's load it and see if your wireless springs to life:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
iwconfig
```

Did a wireless interface wlan0 get created? If not, check the message logs to troubleshoot:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
rfkill list all
```

The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with backslash.

Comment: This is worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work. Still get "lo no wireless connection. Log output: "0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no"

Comment: @DirkHaupt Please start your own new question and be sure to include: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: See here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/735981/unclaimed-network-install-error-127-2-and-execvp-blacklist-sh-permission-deni

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the driver or any packages. The kernel is not able to load the driver.

The solution that worked for me is that I upgraded the Kernel to 4.2.042 and rebooted. I had problem with ethernet as well as wifi. This one upgrade solved both the issues without installing any additional packages.

PC Model is Dell Optiplex 5040.

These kernel packages are upward compatible with ubuntu server 12.04 to ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem looks similar to mine, and I think the new kernel and broadcom drivers are the problem. I ran this, restarted, and it fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

If that does not work then you can look at these two links for some other ideas:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966673#3
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966012#5
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966012#6

If you use the #6 solution please also run the commands found at this link:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966012#9

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first command: says that it is already installed.
The second: doesn't succeed. Here is the last part of the output:

> DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
dpkg: error processing bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Havent tried the third

Comment: I edited the answer with some additional things to try.

Comment: Most of the various commands in the links seem to give errors. It seems that something that comes up a lot is complaints about the wl module in some form, for example "FATAL: Module wl not found". I tried to install it with apt-get, but that mentioned emacs so I'm guessing it's the wrong package. Any ideas about what I should do about this wl module?

Comment: I'm out of ideas :( You might benifit from a fresh install. Especially since you have only had it installed for a day.

Comment: @chili555 because I have an intel card as well, and those commands are the only thing that fixed it. Please do not join a question just to bash. Thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu now. I also updated all the available updates (including something for the kernel), and the WiFi still works. If it was the case that the kernel-update was what screwed my WiFi driver in my previous installment, it doesn't seem to be a problem now. I'll post in this thread again if the problem resurfaces.

Comment: Glad to see you got it worked out.