# Unclaimed Network: install error 127 + 2 and execvp blacklist.sh permission denied with Intel Wireless 8260

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless

I think I have the same problem and have attempted the solution described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/693165) only to have a permission denied error. I have also tried [the following](https://askubuntu.com/a/262150/452147) but get Log output: `0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no`

Wireless LAN:

```
cornelis@Bob:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
3d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
```

More info:  `2-in-1; 802.11a/b/gn/ac WLAN+Bluetooth 4.2; Intel Wireless-AC 8260; M.`

Here's what I see in my terminal after trying the first linked solution:

```
cornelis@Bob:~/Desktop/backports-20150923$ make clean
Generating local configuration database from kernel ... done.
cornelis@Bob:~/Desktop/backports-20150923$ make defconfig-iwlwifi
make[2]: execvp: ./lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: ./lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: Permission denied
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o conf.o conf.c
cc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer   -c -o zconf.tab.o zconf.tab.c
cc   conf.o zconf.tab.o   -o conf
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
cornelis@Bob:~/Desktop/backports-20150923$ make
make[5]: execvp: ./lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: Permission denied
make[5]: execvp: ./lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: Permission denied
make[5]: `conf' is up to date.
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/main.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/backport-4.0.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/backport-4.1.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/backport-4.2.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/backport-4.3.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/lib-rhashtable.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/compat.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-io.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-drv.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-notif-wait.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-eeprom-read.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-eeprom-parse.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-phy-db.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-nvm-parse.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/tx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-1000.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-2000.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-5000.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-6000.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-7000.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-8000.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-devtrace.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/main.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/rs.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/mac80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/ucode.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/tx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/lib.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/calib.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/tt.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/sta.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/rx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/power.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/scan.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/rxon.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/devices.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/led.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/debugfs.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/fw.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/mac80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/nvm.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/ops.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/phy-ctxt.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/mac-ctxt.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/utils.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/rx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/tx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/binding.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/quota.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/sta.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/sf.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/scan.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/time-event.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/rs.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/power.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/coex.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/coex_legacy.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/tt.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/offloading.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/debugfs-vif.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/led.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/tof.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/d3.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/main.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/status.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/driver-ops.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/sta_info.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/wep.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/scan.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/offchannel.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/ht.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/agg-tx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/agg-rx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/vht.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/ibss.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/iface.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/rate.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/michael.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/tkip.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/aes_ccm.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/aes_gcm.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/aes_cmac.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/aes_gmac.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/cfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/ethtool.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/rx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/spectmgmt.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/tx.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/key.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/util.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/wme.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/event.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/chan.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/trace.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/ocb.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/led.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/debugfs_sta.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/debugfs_netdev.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/debugfs_key.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/pm.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/mac80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/core.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/sysfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/radiotap.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/util.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/reg.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/scan.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/nl80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/ibss.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/sme.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/chan.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/ethtool.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/mesh.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/trace.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/ocb.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/debugfs.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/wext-compat.o
  CC [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/wext-sme.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/cfg80211.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 6 modules
  CC      /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/compat.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/compat.ko
  CC      /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
  CC      /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
  CC      /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
  CC      /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/mac80211.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
  CC      /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/cfg80211.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
cornelis@Bob:~/Desktop/backports-20150923$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for cornelis: 
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 6 modules
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/compat.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.19.0-25-generic
make[1]: execvp: ./scripts/blacklist.sh: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 127
make: *** [install] Error 2
cornelis@Bob:~/Desktop/backports-20150923$ sudo make install
sudo: timestamp too far in the future: Feb 20 07:12:41 2016
[sudo] password for cornelis: 
make[1]: Warning: File `backport-include/backport/autoconf.h' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[2]: Warning: File `.config' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[4]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/modules.order' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[5]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/.main.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[5]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[5]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/ethernet/modules.order' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[6]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/modules.order' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[6]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[6]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/modules.order' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[6]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[6]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/modules.order' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[6]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[5]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[5]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/modules.order' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[6]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/.tx.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[7]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/.ucode.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[7]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[7]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/.utils.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[7]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[6]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[5]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[5]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/.wpa.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[5]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[5]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/.wext-sme.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
make[5]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[4]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
  Building modules, stage 2.
make[4]: Warning: File `/home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/.cfg80211.mod.o.cmd' has modification time 2.3e+05 s in the future
  MODPOST 6 modules
make[4]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[2]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/compat/compat.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/cornelis/Desktop/backports-20150923/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.19.0-25-generic
make[1]: execvp: ./scripts/blacklist.sh: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 127
make: *** [install] Error 2
cornelis@Bob:~/Desktop/backports-20150923$
```

I have also tried the following

```
cornelis@Bob:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily[sudo] password for cornelis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-wily
cornelis@Bob:~$
```

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Comment: Yes, I am tethered to my cell phone right now. I am writing this from my laptop and on Ubuntu

Comment: So update the package list first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need those backports. Just upgrade the kernel and firmware by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb
```

and reboot.

Comment: See my edit. Package cannot be found. I am squinting to see if there's a spelling mistake...

Comment: There is no spelling mistake. You need to connect to internet first and run `sudo apt-get update`.